# Does the following paragraph read as if written by a non-English speaker?

Tags: sentence-construction

> "My customers," she explained, "are guys who don’t have girlfriends
>   and have too much loneliness. Or middle-aged men who have wives but
>   don’t feel their company."

The sentence sounds okay for me, but native English speakers said that it didn't sound natural. What's the part that doesn't sound natural and what's the correct alternative?

Comment: The unnatural parts are "have too much loneliness" and "don't feel their company". Though these phrases might come from a native writer, they would be very stylized and sound different than the rest of the sentences they are apart (that's why they sound nonnative). Try to figure out a simpler way of expressing these thoughts since the first parts of the sentences are very simple. I won't go on, otherwise it will be proofreading which is off topic.

Comment: @Peter Oh, you're right. Should I post this in Writers SE or English SE instead?

Comment: I'm sorry but proofreading is off topic. If you have a specific issue, we can help with that but we don't proofread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two phrases that stand out to me (as a native speaker) as feeling 'unnatural' are:

1. 'too much loneliness'
2. 'don't feel their company'

The first is easy to change - we generally treat the emotion 'lonely' as a state of being, rather than something we posess. so a better alternative would be:

> "My customers," she explained, "are guys who don’t have girlfriends
>   and are very lonely."

The second probably requires the use of a different expression in order for it to feel more natural. I'm sure there are many alternatives, possibly better than the ones I can some up with, but based on the tone of the paragraph, my suggestions would be:

> "Or middle-aged men who have wives but don't enjoy their company".

If you want to step outside the phrasing you've used a little, these might be better alternatives:

> "Or middle-aged men who have wives but are looking for something
>   more".
>
> "Or middle-aged men who have wives but are looking for something new".
>
> "Or middle-aged men who have wives but are looking for a little
>   excitement."
>
> "Or middle-aged men who have wives but are looking for something on
>   the side."